# Getting started with Corobot

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'd like to start using ros with a Corobot but I can't find any documentation.
What should i do to install the Corobot package?And are there any tutorials and an urdf model for that robot?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53781/getting-started-with-corobot/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[The ROS Corobot page](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/Corobot) looks like a good place to start.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-31**:
I can't find any urdf file for the robot, though.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-01**:
Contact the maintainer directly for that question.